# Ora - 00472 - PMON process terminated with error (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle

i am technical support in our company, We have encountered this error "Ora-00472" , Also it shows from the SVRMGR23 in ORACLE when connecting to the database, it shows "connected to an idle instance". How can i fix this error?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It depends. What do the alert logs say? You probably have something else going on because pmon failures are symptoms of deeper issues for the most part.

Comment: "Ora-00472 - Pmon processTerminated with error", do you have any solution or suggestion to this error sir? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

can u check if u r database is started.

plz use the command sql>startup

If it is not started normally startup with  pfile or spfile

location of pfile or spfile is $ORACLE_HOME/dbs

sql> startup from pfile=''